# Node request gets werid return value which crashes jsdom

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, httprequest, jsdom

I am using request module to get data from a list of websites then use jsdom to get the DOM and do some stuff.

Some websites are returning weird content (not html).

[image: werid code returned from a website using request module]

The data from this image is then passed to jsdom to get the DOM but it passes this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined
```

I am not sure why is this happening, i viewed the website and it is generating HTML not the gibberish from the screenshot!!

**CODE:**

```
request({
  uri: linkTarget,
  method: "GET",
  timeout: 120000,
  followRedirect: true,
  maxRedirects: 5
}, function(error, response, html){

if (!error) {
    jsdom.env(html,
        ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
        function (errors, window) {                         

            var $ = window.$; // Getting Dom

            linkHtml = "";
            $('body script').remove();
            $('body *').each(function() {
                if($(this).text() !== " "){
                    linkHtml = linkHtml+$(this).text();
                }
            });
```

Comment: do `console.log(errors)` within the callback. Its probable there are some errors stopping the window object from being valid

Comment: @secretformula ok, i did it within jsdom callback & got this in console `[Error: Path must be a string without null bytes.]`

Comment: @secretformula that what the problem is ... i am getting valid html from request module but for some websites it returns gibberish like the one in screenshot

Comment: How are you getting the html? That doesnt look like html to me

Comment: May I see the code that does that please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54233/discussion-between-imran-bughio-and-secretformula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is returned gzipped.  [Use `zlib` to unzip it](http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html):

```
var zlib = require('zlib')
  , request = require('request');

request(params, function (err, res, buffer) {
  if (err) { error(err); }
  zlib.gunzip(buffer, function (err, unzipped) {
    var result = unzipped.toString();
    try {
      result = JSON.parse(result);
      cb(result);
    }
    catch (e) {
      error(e);
    }
  });
});
```